# Add background image to RecyclerView that moves with scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I am trying to add background images, partially covered, to a scrollable view that move along with it. What's the best way to do that?

Below is my attempt. I created an image item, and set the item just below the image to have a negative offset at the top by using `ItemDecoration`. However, as you can see, the item suddenly appears and disappears.

My second idea is just to lump the image and first item into one single item, but that seems less clean. Anybody has some good suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved the sudden appearance/disappearance problem by giving the `RecyclerView` a -150dp `layout_marginBottom`. Now the recycler view extends below the screen and the first item persists until it goes offscreen. I then set 150dp `paddingBottom` to compensate for content loss at the bottom.

Now everything works perfectly. But I consider this approach a little hacky, and would love to see more ideas